# Rigidbody2D velocity random drops to 0 in an infinite runner

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I'm using a rigibody2D on a cube in Unity. I have a constant force been added to slowly increase the speed:

```
rigidbody2D.AddForce (Vector2.right * speed * Time.deltaTime)
```

This works fine, however, every now and them (Seemingly completely random), the velocity is reset to 0 or goes into the minus values. Below is the code for the class:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
public class Player : MonoBehaviour {
    public float speed;
    public float jumpForce;
    private bool isGrounded;

    // Use this for initialization
    private void Start()
    {
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    private void Update()
    {
        rigidbody2D.AddForce (Vector2.right * speed * Time.deltaTime);

        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0)) {
            Jump();
        }

        Debug.Log(rigidbody2D.velocity);
    }

    public void reverseSpeed(){
        speed = -speed;
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D c)
    {
        if (c.gameObject.tag == "Floor")
        {
            isGrounded = true;
        }

        if (c.gameObject.tag == "Inverting") {
            reverseSpeed ();

            //TODO: Needs to match old speed better
            rigidbody2D.AddForce ((-c.relativeVelocity * rigidbody2D.mass) * Time.deltaTime);

            //Try just reversing velocity directly
        }
    }

    private void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D c)
    {
        if (c.gameObject.tag == "Floor")
        {
            isGrounded = false;
        }
    }

    private void Jump()
    {
        //Need changing
        rigidbody2D.AddForce(transform.up * (jumpForce/ Time.deltaTime));
    }
}
```

I've check if there any components on objects causing this, but as far as I can see theres nothing.

Edit: I've done more testing, and in no way is this been caused by a collision with another object.

Comment: Could it be rolling (or sliding) over an object that has the "Inverting" tag set?

Comment: It usually happens mid air, I've double checked that its not colliding with anything